# DB connection issue with Laravel, Jetstream and Inertia

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I've set up a new project using Laravel with Sail (Docker) and Jetstream with Inertia.js, I've gone through the setup but getting this error when accessing the site locally:

```
Illuminate \ Database\ QueryException
PHP 8.1.3
9.3.1
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

    select * from `sessions` where `id` = KdN2zl3PoYshRyfBJOCQi4nNLPnezUJZJi6MgXGR limit 1
```

This can be fixed by changing the `DB_HOST` from `127.0.0.1` to `mysql`, I can then access the site locally, but when when I do something like `php artisan migrate` I get the error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Where with the `DB_HOST` set to `127.0.0.1`, `php artisan migrate` works fine, so by fixing one it breaks the other, please help

Comment: Your running server and your command line console are not being run in the same environment. You are using the wrong console. we need more details about your installation than your code. You might also get more good answers from https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "_This can be fixed by changing the "DB_HOST" from "127.0.0.1" to "mysql"_" Where did you read that? That's incorrect. `DB_CONNECTION` should be `mysql`, not `DB_HOST`

Comment: Are you using Docker?

Comment: @waterloomatt Yes, Laravel Sail

Comment: @brombeer With the DB_HOST set to "mysql", how can I get console artisan commands to work?

Comment: @N69S I'm using Laravel Sail with Docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Laravel Sail you have to use `sail artisan migrate` instead of `php artisan migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Docker container (Sail) in this case, if you want to use the associated database (`docker compose ps` to see all services), you must do `docker compose exec SERVICE_NAME bash` so you can connect to the service, and then run any normal command you would want to.

Because you are using Sail, you must run `sail artisan migrate`:

- `sail artisan` is to run any `php artisan` command.
- `migrate` will, of course, run `php artisan migrate` on the associated database...

So, you must use `mysql` or the name you have on Sail...

Please, read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail) as your issue is 100% explained in there... don't try to be a maigician, read the documentation...